# How to debug why javac is unable to load a library with a valid path in -classpath option?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac

I'm trying to use Apache's PDFBox library. For some reason, javac is unable to load [pdfbox-2.0.28.jar](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/pdfbox/2.0.28/pdfbox-2.0.28.jar). When I run *any* of the following commands in Bash:

```
javac -cp "pdfbox-2.0.28.jar" MyPdf.java
javac -cp ".:pdfbox-2.0.28.jar" MyPdf.java
javac -cp "pdfbox-2.0.28.jar:." MyPdf.java
javac -sourcepath "pdfbox-2.0.28.jar" MyPdf.java
```

I get this error:

```bash
MyPdf.java:1: error: package org.apache.pdfbox does not exist
import org.apache.pdfbox.*;
^
1 error
```

I know that the jar file is not corrupted because I can extract its contents without a problem. The class files within that jar files also exist. The MyPdf.java is a simplistic java code with following content:

```java
import org.apache.pdfbox.*;

public class MyPdf {
    public static void main (String... args) {}
}
```

My directory tree:

```bash
pdf
├── MyPdf.java
├── pdfbox-2.0.28.jar
└── sample.pdf
```

File list of pdfbox-2.0.28.jar file:

```bash
$ unzip -l pdfbox-2.0.28.jar
Archive:  pdfbox-2.0.28.jar
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
    18161  2023-04-10 10:05   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  2023-04-10 12:05   META-INF/
     1655  2023-04-10 10:04   META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
    23477  2023-04-10 10:04   META-INF/LICENSE
      638  2023-04-10 10:04   META-INF/NOTICE
        0  2023-04-10 12:05   META-INF/maven/
        0  2023-04-10 12:05   META-INF/maven/org.apache.pdfbox/
        0  2023-04-10 12:05   META-INF/maven/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/
      134  2023-04-10 10:05   META-INF/maven/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/pom.properties
    43315  2023-04-10 10:04   META-INF/maven/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/pom.xml
        0  2023-04-10 12:05   org/
        0  2023-04-10 12:05   org/apache/
        0  2023-04-10 12:05   org/apache/pdfbox/
        0  2023-04-10 12:05   org/apache/pdfbox/contentstream/
      431  2023-04-10 10:04   org/apache/pdfbox/contentstream/PDContentStream.class
     7327  2023-04-10 10:04   org/apache/pdfbox/contentstream/PDFGraphicsStreamEngine.class
    25077  2023-04-10 10:04   org/apache/pdfbox/contentstream/PDFStreamEngine.class
        0  2023-04-10 12:05   org/apache/pdfbox/contentstream/operator/
     ... snipped ...
     1514  2023-04-10 10:04   org/apache/pdfbox/util/filetypedetector/ByteTrie$ByteTrieNode.class
     2585  2023-04-10 10:04   org/apache/pdfbox/util/filetypedetector/ByteTrie.class
     1880  2023-04-10 10:04   org/apache/pdfbox/util/filetypedetector/FileType.class
     3308  2023-04-10 10:04   org/apache/pdfbox/util/filetypedetector/FileTypeDetector.class
---------                     -------
  5603142                     879 files
```

I looked at some of the search results from this [web search query](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+figure+out+why+jar+file+in+classpath+not+imported+site:stackoverflow.com&client=firefox-b-d&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5nqa-j5j_AhUnSmwGHQ6SD_0QrQIoBHoECBEQBQ&biw=1040&bih=672#ip=1), including the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8084926/4720957) but none of them solved my problem.

How do I figure out what I'm doing wrong? It is not the first time for me to load a library using classpath but I cannot get this thing to work.

Comment: What version of java and what platform are you using?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Oracle JDK 17 LTS (javac 17.0.6) on Arch Linux x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**org.apache.pdfbox.*** doesn't render to any classes, because it doesn't contain any classes in org/apache/pdfbox dir inside your jar. You should import something like **org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.*** — anything with actual classes inside. Try it.

Comment: javac does compile correctly when I followed your instructions. I was under the impression that `.*` works irrespective of if a class exists within the root directory of the package of not.

Comment: If there are no compilable classes within a folder, then it isn't recognised as a java package. And you can't import anything that is not a package. Otherwise you would be able to do something like "import org.*" or even "import *". Which doesn't make any sense of course.

Comment: @user47 - Your impression is incorrect.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html ... and read the section entitled "Apparent Hierarchies of Packages".

Comment: And read https://stackoverflow.com/a/15857488/139985 for more explanation.